# Is it possible to create more Data Fields after Migrations have taken place?

Tags: python, django

I wanted to ask if it is possible to add more integerfields and charfields to a model if it has already been migrated to an SQLite database.

Comment: Please read an article or do a tutorial on what django and what a db is. You can add coloums with migrations as often as you want, no data will be overwritten. just do your changes and migrate.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial02/#creating-models

Answer (score 0):

Yes after every new addition/deletion of fields to/from your model you need to do `makemigrations` and `migrate` and Django will modify your sqlite database accordingly.

If there is existing data and you add a new field, it has to be either nullable or you need to provide a sensible default for existing data for that new column.

If you remove a field, that field will be removed but your data will remain intact without the removed column.

Comment: So will that overwrite the existing data?

Comment: clarified in answer